# How to Rmic and Rmiregistry

Tags: java, rmi

I need to know how can I run Rmic. I have programmed my app in Java Eclipse and now I need to run Rmic. I tried it by running CMD, changing directory to Bin folder of my eclipse project and then typing command Rmic class name. It shows error unrecognised command. Is I am doing something wrong?

Comment: Do you have the bin directory of a Java SDK (not JRE) on your PATH? The rmic tool is part of the Java SDK.

Comment: If you're using Eclipse or indeed any IDE why are you trying to to it by hand at all?

Answer (score 0):

I use Maven and this is what I have in my pom file. It works quite well.

```
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>rmic-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>rmi package</id>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>package</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <outputDirectory>${project.build.outputDirectory}</outputDirectory>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*_Stub*</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
            <execution>
                <id>rmi compilation</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>rmic</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <outputDirectory>${project.build.outputDirectory}</outputDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
```